# How to execute computation per executor in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, lazy-initialization

In my computation, I

- first broadcast some data, say `bc`,
- then compute some big data shared by all executor/partition:`val shared = f(bc)`
- then run the distributed computing, using shared data

To avoid computing the `shared` data on all RDD items, I can use `.mapPartitions` but I have much more partitions than executors. So it run the computation of shared data more times than necessary.

I found a simple method to compute the shared data only once per executor (which I understood is the JVM actually running the spark tasks): using `lazy val` on the broadcast data.

```
// class to be Broadcast
case class BC(input: WhatEver){
  lazy val shared = f(input)
}

// in the spark code
val sc = ... // init SparkContext
val bc = sc.broadcast(BC(...))

val initRdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 10000, numSlices = 10000)
initRDD.map{ i =>
  val shared = bc.value.shared
  ... // run computation using shared data
}
```

I think this does what I want, but

1. I am not sure, can someone guaranties it?
2. I am not sure lazy val is the best way to manage concurrent access, especially with respect to the spark internal distribution system. Is there a better way?
3. if computing `shared` fails, I think it will be recomputed for all RDD items with possible retries, instead of simply stopping the whole job with a unique error.

So, is there a better way?

Comment: why don't you just calculated `shared` and then brodcast this?

Comment: I should have explain that: shared is fast to compute but very big (100s of MB, could even be >1GB). Imagine lookup tables used in algorithm optimizations. Computing it is faster than serialization + network + deserialization